# jsgrid in HTML5 Template

Tags: html, jsgrid

I am trying to repeat jsgrid via an HTML5 template, same ajax call as datasource with different variable.
Only the first grid renders.

It is doable, and if so, can you please provide guidance?

Thanks.

Here is the script:

```js
var template = document.querySelector('template').content;                
for (var i = 0; i < distinctQuote.length; i++) 
{

     $('.jsSnapshot').jsGrid({
          width: "100%",
          height: "auto",

          inserting: false,
          editing: true,
          sorting: true,
          autoload: true,
          noDataContent: "No record found",

          controller: {
               loadData: function () {
                  var d = $.Deferred();
                  $.ajax({
                                url: "/AJAXWebServices/UnderwriterWorksheet/UnderwriterWorksheet.asmx/GetQuickSnapshotByQuoteId",
                                data: { quoteId: distinctQuote[i] },
                                dataType: "json",
                                type: "post"
                            }).done(function (response) {
                                d.resolve(response);
                            });

                            return d.promise();
                        }
                    },

             fields: [
                        { name: "QuickSnapShotId", type: "number", visible: false },
                        { name: "QuickSnapShotFieldId", type: "number", visible: false },
                        { name: "QuickSnapShotFieldName", title:"", type: "string", width: 100, validate: "required" },
                        { name: "CurrentYear", title:"Current Year", type: "number", width: 200, validate: "required" },
                        { name: "LastYear", title:"Last Year", type: "number", width: 200 }
                    ]
                });

    document.querySelector('#container').appendChild(document.importNode(template, true));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Working code:

```
 var template = document.querySelector('#template').content;                
 for (var i = 0; i < distinctQuote.length; i++) {

                    document.querySelector('#container').appendChild(document.importNode(template, true));

                    $('.jsGridSnapshot').last().jsGrid({
                        width: "100%",
                        height: "auto",

                        inserting: false,
                        editing: true,
                        sorting: true,
                        autoload: true,
                        noDataContent: "No record found",

                        controller: {
                            loadData: function () {
                                var d = $.Deferred();
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "/AJAXWebServices/UnderwriterWorksheet/UnderwriterWorksheet.asmx/GetQuickSnapshotByQuoteId",
                                    data: { quoteId: distinctQuote[i] },
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    type: "post"
                                }).done(function (response) {
                                    d.resolve(response);
                                });

                                return d.promise();
                            }
                        },

                        fields: [
                            { name: "QuickSnapShotId", type: "number", visible: false },
                            { name: "QuoteId", type: "number", visible: false },
                            { name: "QuickSnapShotFieldId", type: "number", visible: false },
                            { name: "QuickSnapShotFieldName", title:"", type: "string", width: 100, validate: "required" },
                            { name: "CurrentYear", title:"Current Year", type: "number", width: 200, validate: "required" },
                            { name: "LastYear", title:"Last Year", type: "number", width: 200, validate: "required" }
                        ],

                        });                        
                }
            }
```